# State Properties of AngularJS for form validation is not returning a value

Tags: angularjs

```
**This is my code snippet of an html file**
              <form name="demoForm" novalidate ng-submit="" role="form">
                   <p>
                       Text Input Status : <br />
                       Error[Bind to validation attribute] : {{demoForm.name.$error}}<br />
                       Pristine[No interaction yet] : {{demoForm.name.$pristine}}<br />
                       Touched[Tabbed out] : {{demoForm.name.$touched}}<br />
                       Untouched[Not tabbed out] : {{demoForm.name.$untouched}}<br />
                       Valid[Valid model] : {{demoForm.name.$valid}}<br />
                       Invalid[Invalid model] : {{demoForm.name.$invalid}}<br />
                       Dirty[Change the value once at least] : {{demoForm.name.$dirty}}
                   </p>
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a text" ng-required="true" />
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a number" />
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
               </form>
```

The values of the state properties mainly inside paragragh tags below Text Input Status is not displaying even if its default value probably(if it exists). The script tag is correctly written. But I just don't get why it's not displaying its value

Comment: Try to place your <p> tag below your inputs and see if it is working

Comment: @Vivz it's still the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-model` on your input elements. The name attribute of your input field is to refer that particular element but your form will be checking the value of `ng-model`  variable for triggering validations against that input.  The following taken from angular documentation of forms can give you clearer idea.

"*A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can optionally be published into the scope using the name attribute.
**Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control**. The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance.
This implies that the internal state of both the form and the control is available for binding in the view using the standard binding primitives.*"

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",function($scope){

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
 <form name="demoForm" novalidate  role="form" ng-submit="">
                   <p>
                       Text Input Status : <br />
                       Error[Bind to validation attribute] : {{demoForm.name.$error}}<br />
                       Pristine[No interaction yet] : {{demoForm.name.$pristine}}<br />
                       Touched[Tabbed out] : {{demoForm.name.$touched}}<br />
                       Untouched[Not tabbed out] : {{demoForm.name.$untouched}}<br />
                       Valid[Valid model] : {{demoForm.name.$valid}}<br />
                       Invalid[Invalid model] : {{demoForm.name.$invalid}}<br />
                       Dirty[Change the value once at least] : {{demoForm.name.$dirty}}
                   </p>
                    <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a text" ng-required="true" />
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a number" />
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
               </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's now working. But how does ng-model affects it? Say for instance, in  demoForm.name.$pristine, 'name' refers to the name attribute. So we're refering right to the name attribute and not to the ng-model directive.
PS. I tried to change the value of ng-model to other string and then it's still working. That make sense that we are referring to the input name attribute but does that not make sense to me that putting the ng-model fix the problem :)

Comment: In the statement, "The name attribute of your input field is to refer that particular element but your form will be checking the value of ng-model variable for triggering validations." But it is not required to have name attribute and ng-model the same value?

Comment: "Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control." See here it is clearly stating that the name attribute helps the form instance to have a grip on ng-model value for triggering validations. In your question, the ng-model is absent. So, the name attribute is not helping the form instance to trigger validations since validations need ng-model for check. Otherwise how will the form know if the input is empty or not or etc....

Comment: I get it now( the validation part )since ng-model will be the basis of the checking. Thanks really a lot for helping me understand. :) Thanks once more.